# Indeterminate progressbar not stopping in python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to get a progressbar in python tkinter to start and stop for a download process. I tried to set up a thread for the download progress and start the process bar. However, the bar keeps on running and I get an "if self._is_stopped or not self._started.is_set():RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded" error.

Here is the code:

```py
import time
import threading
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk
from six.moves import urllib

def start_thread():
    b_start['state'] = 'disable'
    progbar.start()
    thread = threading.Thread(target=tasks)
    thread.start()
    root.after(50, check_thread(thread))

def check_thread(thread):
    if thread.is_alive():
        root.after(50, check_thread(thread))
    else:
        progbar.stop()
        b_start['state'] = 'normal'

def download_func():
    urllib.request.urlretrieve('ftp://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/uniprot/knowledgebase/uniprot_sprot_varsplic.fasta.gz', 'uni.dat')

def tasks():
    download_func()

root = tkinter.Tk()

progbar = ttk.Progressbar(root)
progbar.config(maximum=8,mode='indeterminate')
progbar.pack()

b_start = ttk.Button(root, text='Start',command=start_thread)
b_start.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

What am I doing wrong?!

Cheers,
Curly

Comment: `root.after(50, check_thread(thread))` should be `root.after(50, lambda: check_thread(thread))`, otherwise you execute the function immediately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from the function

```
def check_thread(thread):
    if thread.is_alive():
        root.after(50, check_thread(thread))
    else:
        progbar.stop()
        b_start['state'] = 'normal'
```

Indeed,

```
root.after(50, check_thread(thread))
```

immediately  re-execute `check_thread`, leading to the `RecursionError`. The correct syntax for `after` is `root.after(<delay>, <function to execute>)`, therefore, here replacing the above line by

```
root.after(50, lambda: check_thread(thread))
```

solve the issue.